# Why grep gives error for search pattern i.e. grep: <some pattern>: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, bash, unix, grep

I want to print the selected lines using grep pattern matching. I am using following command -

```
cat MyTest.txt | grep -v -E B1 "EEB|SET|PET"
grep: EEB|SET|PET: No such file or directory
```

I am always getting above grep error.

- 1. I want to print the line which matches pattern or patterns I have mentioned i.e EEB or SET or PET or All of these and
- 2. A single line prior to matching line. hence option `-B1`

Comment: looks like you miss the minus before `B1`

Comment: It s because you didnt add a file to search for @anubhava seems to have the right idea

Answer (score 1):

You can use this command without useless `cat`:

```
grep -v -E -B1 "EEB|SET|PET" MyTest.txt
```

Note `-` before `B1`.

However from your description it appears you may not need `-v` (inverse results) and want this:

```
grep -E -B1 "EEB|SET|PET" MyTest.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Grep has the following syntax:

```
grep options pattern input_file_names
```

where options are optional, but not pattern. So B1 without "-" is used as pattern and "EEB|SET|PET" as file_names.

You should change "B1" to "-B1".

As recommendation

```
cat MyTest.txt | grep -v -E -B1 "EEB|SET|PET"
```

to

```
grep -v -E -B1 "EEB|SET|PET" MyTest.txt
```